# Remove Machines from VMware Horizon View with PowerCLI

Tags: vmware, powercli, horizon

We often add and remove machines from a manual Desktop Pool on our Horizon server. Registering the machine is done with an install script. When we're done with a machine we want to un-register it from the server. The only way we have found to do this is to log into the web portal and manually delete each one. This is cumbersome and time-consuming when we have large numbers of machines to un-register.

The machines that will need to be un-registered will have similar names. Is there a way to automate this with PowerCLI?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can,

```
$VM = Get-VM -Name nameOfVM
Remove-VM $VM
```

Full example you can find [here](https://blogs.vmware.com/euc/2017/01/vmware-horizon-7-powercli-6-5.html)

Comment: Remove-VM seems to delete the VM completely. Don't want to do that. Just want to un-register it with the View Horizon server.  

EDIT: This will find the vCenter VMs. The ones we're trying to manage are in a manual desktop pool and are classified a "Others" (as opposed to vCenter VMs or RDS Hosts).   

They're Linux machines, if that clears anything up.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `powercli 6.5` ? VMWare: "PowerCLI 6.5 introduced a brand new, completely re-written, module for Horizon View"

Comment: Have you seen [that](http://www.virtu-al.net/2016/12/08/getting-started-powercli-6-5-horizon-view/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had this question answered already, but there are a couple of ways that you can do this, depending on the version of PowerCLI that you have installed. The easiest way right now is to get the latest version of PowerCLI and make sure that you install the View module along with it. From here, peruse through the View API (https://code.vmware.com/web/dp/explorer-apis?id=58)

VMware also has a helper PSM1 script in their Example gallery, which is available via github: https://github.com/vmware/PowerCLI-Example-Scripts/tree/master/Modules/VMware.Hv.Helper